# Удаленное подключение к PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите: каким образом возможно сделать удаленное подключение к базе данных PostgreSQL, которая находится на другом компьютере? Я пробовал это реализовать, опираясь на данную [статью](https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=pgsql-remote). Однако при попытке подключиться выдается ошибка: connected timed out ... is the server running on host (далее ip) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Если действительно всё сделали, как описано в статье, то возможно на сервере запущен брандмауэр, блокирующий подключения к порту.

Comment: Я отключил брандмауэр на обоих устройствах и добавил в правила порт 5432, однако никак это не помогло. Что еще я мог сделать не так?

Comment: Какой файл конфигурации используется при старте лучше смотреть запросом `show config_file;`. Указанный в статье способ например даст неверный результат для debian и ubuntu, где конфиги базы размещены в `/etc`

Answer (score 0):

все верно.
Поправить надо файлы postgresql.conf и pg_hba.conf.

Найти их размещение можно вот так:

```
find / -name 'postgresql.conf' 2>/dev/null

find / -name 'pg_hba.conf' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Если к базе есть доступ, то лучше у неё спросить где конфиги: `show hba_file;` для pg_hba.conf и `show config_file;` для основного конфига